# LINQ-to-SQL and SQL Compact - database file sharing problem

Tags: linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce

I'm learing LINQ-to-SQL right now and i have wrote a simple application that define SQL data:

```
  [Table( Name = "items" )]
  public class Item
  {
    [ Column( IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true ) ]
    public int Id;
    [ Column ]
    public string Name;
  }
```

I have launched 2 copy of application connected to the same .sdf file and tested if all database modifications in one application affects another application. But strange thing arise. If i use InsertOnSubmit() and DeleteOnSubmit() in one application, added/removed items are instantly visible in other application via 'select' LINQ queue. But if i try to modify 'Name' field in one application, it is NOT visible in other applicaton until it reconnects the database :(. The test code i use:

```
  var Items = from c in db.Items
              where Id == c.Id
              select c;
  foreach( var Item in Items )
  {
    Item.Name = "new name";
    break;
  }
  db.SubmitChanges();
```

Can anyone suggest what i'm doing wrong and why InsertOnSubmit()/DeleteOnSubmit works and SubmitChanges() don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to how Linq-to-Sql manages [Object Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399376.aspx). If you query for the same entity more than once, you will always receive the same object representing the *row* in the database.

When you `insert` or `delete` entities, you are able to see the changes from another client because Linq-to-Sql will need to create/delete the objects associated with those entities and, if there are no conflicts, this presents no problem.

Updating has a different behavior that's explained in the [Object Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399376.aspx) article.

> LINQ to SQL uses this approach to
>   manage the integrity of local objects
>   in order to support optimistic
>   updates. Because the only changes that
>   occur after the object is at first
>   created are those made by the
>   application, the intent of the
>   application is clear.

If you need the most updated data from the database, use the [`DataContext.Refresh`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.refresh.aspx) with `RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues`.